# Parse array and check if items are wrapped between start and end

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have an array of items like this one:

```
[
    { id: 1, val: 'start' },
    { id: 2, val: 'xxx' },
    { id: 3, val: 'yyy' },
    { id: 4, val: 'end' },
    { id: 5, val: 'start' },
    { id: 6, val: 'zzz' },
    { id: 7, val: 'end' },
    { id: 8, val: 'aaa' }
]
```

*I want to make sure that if there's a `start`, there should be an `end` (and the other way around) and if there's a `start / end` couple, there should be something in the middle (that is not a start or an end)*

I thought about looping through the array and for each occurence of `start` loop again from that index to find at least 1 normal item, no start item and 1 end item.

I'm not good at recursion so that would end up being the most buggy nested for loop ever created.

I thought about flattening the array values to get something like

`startxxxyyyendstartzzzendaaa` and come up with a regex that works like finding html opening and closing tags. But again I'm not good at regex...

I also made an attempt using Array.reduce() and failed.

Do you have a good approach to this problem?

Comment: is `'start', 'x', 'start', 'y', 'end', 'z', 'end'` valid? If so, is the first start coupled with the last end or do they overlap?

Comment: @Cid no, "tags" cannot be nested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a fairly straightforward way to do it. It keeps a counter - when "start" is found it increments the counter. When "end" is found it decrements it. If the counter ever falls below `0` there is an error (an extra "end"). If the counter gets greater than 1 there is an error (an extra "start"). At the end of the loop, if the counter does not equal `0` there is an error. There is also extra code to check if a "start" is immediately followed by an "end".

```
let a = [
    { id: 1, val: 'start' },
    { id: 2, val: 'xxx' },
    { id: 3, val: 'yyy' },
    { id: 4, val: 'end' },
    { id: 5, val: 'start' },
    { id: 6, val: 'zzz' },
    { id: 7, val: 'end' },
    { id: 8, val: 'aaa' }
];

let count = 0;
let last = null;
for (let e of a) {
    if (e.val === 'start') count++;
    else if (e.val == 'end') {
        count--;
        if (last === 'start') count = -1;
    }
    if (count < 0 || count > 1) break;
    last = e.val;
}
// If count != 0 here, there was an error
if (count != 0) console.log("failed");
else console.log("passed");
```

Comment: You only need a counter if nesting should be supported, otherwise a simple boolean would be enough.

Answer (score 2):

### Thinking in state machines

We can think about this problem as a transition between states in a well-defined machine.  Here is a [diagram](https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid-live-editor/edit/#eyJjb2RlIjoic3RhdGVEaWFncmFtLXYyXG4gICAgc3RhdGUgXCJOZXV0cmFsICgjKS5cIiBhcyBOZXV0cmFsXG4gICAgWypdIC0tPiBOZXV0cmFsXG4gICAgTmV1dHJhbCAtLT4gT3BlbiA6IHN0YXJ0XG4gICAgTmV1dHJhbCAtLT4gTmV1dHJhbCA6ICpcbiAgICBOZXV0cmFsIC0tPiBFcnJvciA6IGVuZFxuICAgIE9wZW4gLS0-IEVycm9yIDogc3RhcnRcbiAgICBPcGVuIC0tPiBFcnJvciA6IGVuZFxuICAgIE9wZW4gLS0-IEZpbGxlZCA6ICpcbiAgICBGaWxsZWQgLS0-IEZpbGxlZCA6ICpcbiAgICBGaWxsZWQgLS0-IEVycm9yIDogc3RhcnRcbiAgICBGaWxsZWQgLS0-IE5ldXRyYWwgOiBlbmRcbiAgICBFcnJvciAtLT4gIEVycm9yOiAqXG4gICIsIm1lcm1haWQiOiJ7XG4gIFwidGhlbWVcIjogXCJkZWZhdWx0XCJcbn0iLCJ1cGRhdGVFZGl0b3IiOmZhbHNlLCJhdXRvU3luYyI6dHJ1ZSwidXBkYXRlRGlhZ3JhbSI6ZmFsc2V9) of a [finite state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) which start with the initial state of `Neutral` and which has just one accepting state (`#`), also `Neutral`.

[image: state diagram]

On each token -- `'start'`, `'end'`, or other (`'*'`) -- we transition to a state based on the state we're in and the value of the token.  We can use the function below to take that initial state, the list of accepting states, and the list of transitions, and get back a function which takes a series of tokens and reports whether after running through all of them, the function ends in one of the accepting states.

Here we name the states, `Neutral`, for when everything we've seen so far is already balanced out; `Open`, for when we've seen the `start` token, but no `end` token nor any other intermediate token; `Filled` for when we have seen the `start` token and at least one intermediate token (anything but `start` or `end`); and `Error`, for when we've already hit a point where the stream of tokens is invalid.  We write the transitions with state names, and either token values or `*` as a wildcard allowing any token besides `start` and `end`.

We could code it like this:

```js
const stateMachine = (initial, accepting, rules) => (xs) =>
  accepting .includes (xs .reduce (
    (c, x) => (
      rules .find(([s, t]) => s == c && x == t) ||    // exact match
      rules .find(([s, t]) => s == c && t == '*') ||  // generic match
      [, , c]                                         // no match, so no transition
    ) [2],
    initial
  ))

const myMachine = stateMachine ('Neutral', ['Neutral'], [
  [ 'Neutral', 'start', 'Open' ],
  [ 'Neutral', 'end',   'Error' ],
  [ 'Neutral', '*',     'Neutral' ],
  [ 'Open',    'start', 'Error' ],
  [ 'Open',    'end',   'Error' ],
  [ 'Open',    '*',     'Filled' ],
  [ 'Filled',  'start', 'Error' ],
  [ 'Filled',  'end',   'Neutral' ],
  [ 'Filled',  '*',     'Filled' ],
  [ 'Error',   '*',     'Error' ],
])

const check = (xs) => 
  myMachine ([...xs] .map (({val}) => val))

const a = [{id: 1, val: 'start'}, {id: 2, val: 'xxx'}, {id: 3, val: 'yyy'}, {id: 4, val: 'end'}, {id: 5, val: 'start'}, {id: 6, val: 'zzz'}, {id: 7, val: 'end'}, {id: 8, val: 'aaa'}]

console .log (check (a))
```

**`stateMachine`** is a generic function, which we use to build our particular instance.  We call it using our initial state, an array of at least one accepting states, and the list of transition rules, which are simply triples containing a current state, a token or wildcard, and a resulting state.

**`myMachine`** is an instance created by passing the transition rules needed to describe the your grammar.

We wrap that in **`check`**, which converts an array (or other iterable) of input items (such as `{id: 2, val: 'xxx'}`) into an array of tokens to test, then calls `myMachine` with the results.

### Variations

- We should note that our diagram has arrows from states back to themselves with a wildcard match.  So I included them in the table (`['Neutral', '*', 'Neutral']`, `['Filled', '*', 'Filled']` and `['Error', '*', 'Error']`) for clarity.  But the way `stateMachine` works, we can skip these without harm; if no transition match is found, we simply maintain our current state.
- A sharp eye might have noticed that we might simplify `stateMachine` from

  ```js
  rules .find(([s, t]) => s == c && x == t) ||    
  rules .find(([s, t]) => s == c && t == '*')
  ```

  to

  ```js
  rules .find(([s, t]) => s == c && (x == t || t == '*'))
  ```

  That's correct; we could do so.  But it would introduce a required ordering into the transition rules.  All rules for a single input state, like `['State1', 'token', 'State2']` would need to come before wildcards like `['State1', '*', 'State3']`.  I find it simpler like this, where my transitions are unordered, but others might not.

### Is it worthwhile?

This is more code than in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67807771) from Jonny Mopp, even if you don't include the reusable `stateMachine` function.  Is it worth it?  Maybe not for this specific problem.  But maybe so, too.  We've turned some imperative code into declarative configuration, and that is very often a win.  And this will scale to much larger state machines.

### Technical disclaimer

We are not entirely following the mathematical notion of a finite state machine, because our input alphabet is not finite; we use a wildcard.  We could easily patch this up by preprocessing our tokens to transform all unknown ones into a single dummy token, but it doesn't seem worthwhile for these purposes.  I don't find this a big deal, but some pedants might.